# Regex uppercase separation but not separating more than 1 next to each other

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have array of values which I have to separate by their uppercase. But there are some cases where the value of the array has 2, 3 or 4 serial uppercases that I must not separate. Here are some values:

```
ERISACheckL 
ERISA404cCheckL 
F401kC  
DisclosureG 
SafeHarborE
```

To be clear result must be:

```
ERISA Check L   
ERISA 404c Check L  
F 401k C    
Disclosure G    
Safe Harbor E
```

I tried using:

```
value.match(/[A-Z].*[A-Z]/g).join(" ")
```

But of couse it is not working for serial letters.

Comment: Why is `401k` not splitted and `404c` is?

Comment: @Thefourthbird my mistake. Corrected it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be matching 1 or more uppercase characters asserting what is directly to the right is not a lowercase character, or get the position where what is on the left is a char a-z or digit, and on the right is an uppercase char.

The use split and use a capture group for the pattern to keep it in the result.

```
([A-Z]+(?![a-z]))|(?<=[\da-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

- `(` Capture **group 1** (To be kept using split)

  - `[A-Z]+(?![a-z])` Match 1+ uppercase chars asserting what is directly to the right is a-z
- `)` Close group 1
- `|` Or
- `(?<=[\da-z])(?=[A-Z])` Get the postion where what is directly to left is either a-z or a digit and what is directly to the right is A-Z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V0YYv2/1)

```js
const pattern = /([A-Z]+(?![a-z]))|(?<=[\da-z])(?=[A-Z])/;
[
  "ERISACheckL",
  "ERISA404cCheckL",
  "F401kC",
  "DisclosureG",
  "SafeHarborE"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.split(pattern).filter(Boolean).join(" ")))
```

---

Another option is to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` matching the different parts:

```
[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+[a-z]+
```

- `[A-Z]+(?![a-z])` Match 1+ uppercase chars asserting what is directly to the right is a-z
- `|` Or
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` Match A-Z optionally followed by a-z to also match single uppercase chars
- `|` Or
- `\d+[a-z]+` match 1+ digits and 1+ chars a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l7WUKP/1)

```js
const pattern = /[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+[a-z]+/g;
[
  "ERISACheckL",
  "ERISA404cCheckL",
  "F401kC",
  "DisclosureG",
  "SafeHarborE"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(pattern).join(" ")))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function formatString(str) {
  return str.replace(/([A-Z][a-z]+|\d+[a-z]+)/g, ' $1 ').replace('  ', ' ').trim();
}

// test
[
  'ERISACheckL',
  'ERISA404cCheckL',
  'F401kC',
  'DisclosureG',
  'SafeHarborE'
].forEach(item => {
  console.log(formatString(item));
});
```